# Get all Django records created since last login

Tags: django, models, records

Using Django models, is there a filter I can use to select all records created after a certain date? I'm not sure what syntax or filter I should use to get all records newer than my last_login.

I wouldn't mind doing it with a Q advanced query, but the simpler the better!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you don't need the current datetime if you want to select all records created after a certain date. Just use a filter with a lookup like: field_date__gte=last_login. It's not necessary to use range here. For example:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(my_model_date__gte=last_login)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed. I had to search a bit to find the field lookup you used (I'm still a Django novice) and found documentation here in case anyone needs it: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#gte

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

first, get the user last_login:

```
last_login = user.last_login
```

then you can filter your data as you want like this:

```
Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__range=(last_login, datetime.datetime.now()))
```

hope it helps...

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This solution works great, but I accepted the other answer for its more simple implementation.

Comment: The other answer is short, but does not fit your needs if you need to include the last login date... I mean only looks for the entries that have a date GREATER than last_login... it does not include last_login as a part of result..

Comment: The "gte" lookup will select values greater than or equal to the last_login value