# Django + all rows greater than today

Tags: mysql, django

I was reading other questions similar to this ( [Get all Django records created since last login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9493342/get-all-django-records-created-since-last-login)), but could not find the exact answer to what I am looking for. I have a table with list of events taking place. I have a `start_time` and `end_time` (both are `datetime` values). I want to get all events that have not **ended** yet. Is there a way to do that with the Django framework? I know how to do it through straight SQL but i'd rather avoid doing that if the framework can do it.

**[EDIT]**

Here is part of the model. Basically I want the current `datetime` value, and want to get anything that is less than the `end_time`.

```
class Event(models.Model):
        class Meta:
            db_table = 'event'

        description = models.TextField()
        start_time = models.DateTimeField()
        end_time = models.DateTimeField()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done easily in Django:

```
Event.objects.filter(end_time__gt=datetime.now())
```

`end_time__gt` means you want to perform a greather-than query on the `end_time` field.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters